# DataGridView records being saved as empty cells

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am developing a C# WinForms Solution in VS 2015 Professional. In on my my forms, I have a DataGridView that is not correctly saving the rows.  After I enter data and save, it saves blank cells.  This started happening after I implemented the code below.  I appreciate your time and help.  Thank you!

```
  private void Alunos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            this.tbl_cursosTableAdapter.Fill(this.bremingtonDataSet.tbl_cursos);
            this.tbl_modulosTableAdapter.Fill(this.bremingtonDataSet.tbl_modulos);
            this.tbl_turmasTableAdapter.Fill(this.bremingtonDataSet.tbl_turmas);
            this.tbl_alunosTableAdapter.Fill(this.bremingtonDataSet.tbl_alunos);
            this.tbl_alunos_subTableAdapter.Fill(this.bremingtonDataSet.tbl_alunos_sub);

            DataView dv = new DataView(bremingtonDataSet.Tables["tbl_modulos"]);
            filteredModulosBS.DataSource = dv;
       }

        private void tbl_alunos_subDataGridView_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == comboBoxModulo.Index)
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgcb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)tbl_alunos_subDataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
                dgcb.DataSource = filteredModulosBS;
                this.filteredModulosBS.Filter = "CodCurso=" + this.tbl_alunos_subDataGridView[e.ColumnIndex - 1, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();                
            }
        }

    private void tbl_alunos_subDataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == this.comboBoxModulo.Index)
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell dgcb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)tbl_alunos_subDataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
            dgcb.DataSource = tblmodulosBindingSource;
            this.filteredModulosBS.RemoveFilter();
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you stepped through the code using the debugger..?

Comment: Yes, I did and it doesn't give me any error messages...

Comment: just because it doesn't give errors doesn't mean anything what you need to do is figure out why what you are trying to bind and or fill, is not presenting the data you are expecting..

Comment: If I knew how to do that, I probably wouldn't be asking for help here...  But thanks anyways for your feedback.  :)

Comment: so you are saying to do not know how to use the debugger and evaluate the variables using the quick watch..?

Comment: I really don't...  My whole programming experience is with MS Access and VBA.  I am totally new to VS and C#.

Comment: do a google search or YouTube search on how to use the debugger.. you stated earlier `Yes` that you did step through the code and used the debugger..

Comment: Yes, I know how to run the debugger, but that's about it.   I had never heard of Quick Watch...

Comment: the internet is at your disposal do you know how to execute a simple search I gave you all the advice short of fixing your code for you.. good luck

Comment: Thank you.  I'm going to keep searching.